# set RestAssured.port in main project and in the library project

Tags: maven, testing, port, rest-assured

I have two Maven projects. One is used in second as a dependency.
Main project uses RestAssured to set static field e.g. RestAssured.port = 1111; 
Now I want use RestAssured to set port for different server in library project e.g. RestAssured.port = 2222.
How does this static value behave in main project if I initiate object from library and this object sets RestAssured.port to 2222?
Dose it override RestAssured.port = 1111 in main project to 2222 or there will be different value for main project and for library?

Comment: I verified it and it turned out that if you set static value in library it affects this value in main project too. So if I set e.g. RestAssured.port = 1111 in main project and then initiated Object from library which set RestAssured.port = 2222 it changed RestAssured.port in main project for 2222